# How to insert dynamic post array php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, arrays

i am sorry this hard to explain, but i will try as i know.

I have multiple input post with custom condition, custom condition that mean can be as much as it can.

HTML

```
<input name="type[]" value="type 1">
    <input name="var[]" value="Var 1">
    <input name="var[]" value="Var 2">
    <input name="var[]" value="Var 3">
<input name="type[]" value="type 2">
    <input name="var[]" value="Var 1 for type 2">
    <input name="var[]" value="Var 2 for type 2">
```

for input name **type[]** can be added as custom via JQuery, and also for **var[]** but if var[] added, it will be inserted as array under type[]

and i want to serialize that value to database with this array result

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( 
    [type 1] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
            [menu_name] => var 1
        ) 
        [1] => Array ( 
            [menu_name] => var 2
        ) 
        [2] => Array ( 
            [menu_name] => var 3
        ) 
    ) 
) 
[1] => Array ( 
    [Type 2] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
            [menu_name] => Var 1 for type 2
        )
        [1] => Array ( 
            [menu_name] => Var 2 for type 2
        )
    ) 
) 
)
```

But the problem is, i dont exactly know how the logic to insert that array with **$_POST** syntax, so the result will be as like array result above

Comment: Tried nested for loop ?

Comment: You should change the html structure.

Comment: @phplover but how to move value var[] in under of type[] array ?

Comment: Vars input name change it to `type[var]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add braces `[]` to the names of inputs

```
<input name="type[0]" value="type 1">
<input name="type[0][var][]" value="Var 1">
<input name="type[0][var][]" value="Var 2">
<input name="type[0][var][]" value="Var 3">
<input name="type[1]" value="type 2">
<input name="type[1][var][]" value="Var 1 for type 2">
<input name="type[1][var][]" value="Var 2 for type 2">
```

**EDIT**

```
$types = $_POST['type'];
$types[0]['var'][1];
```

Comment: Btw, how to get that post value?
for type = $_POST['type'];
var = $_POST['var'];
i am not sure for var

Comment: Hello i have try it, and result is i missing the type value, i have print the result it displaying all but except type value, i use $variable = serialize($_POST['type']); to insert to database, am i wrong?

Comment: first type value is `$_POST['type'][0]` because `$_POST['type']` is an array

Answer (score 0):

You need this HTML structure to post data as you want :

```html
<input name="type[1][var][1]" value="type 1 var 1">
<input name="type[1][var][2]" value="type 1 var 2">
<input name="type[1][var][3]" value="type 1 var 3">
<input name="type[2][var][1]" value="type 2 var 1">
<input name="type[2][var][2]" value="type 2 var 2">
```

Comment: Sure.. Let us know if there is any issue.

Comment: your answer is good, but the most completed answer is in above, thankyou